# Ada - Subprogram determining the biggest number

Tags: ada

The task is simple :

Create a subprogram of type function that receives exactly two parameters, both floats and returns the value of the number that is the greatest.

The execution should go as following:

Type in two floats: **-13.12 2**

-- User types in two numbers marked in bold

The greatest value was : 2.00

This is my code:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;       use Ada.Text_IO;   
with Ada.Float_Text_IO; use Ada.Float_Text_IO;
 
procedure Test is
   
    function Value(Float_1, Float_2 : in Float) return Float is
    begin  
        if Float_1 > Float_2 then
            return Float_1;
        elsif Float_2 > Float_1 then
            return Float_2;
        end if;
    end Value;
   
    Float_1, Float_2 : Float;
   
begin
    Put("Type in two numbers: ");
    Get(Float_1);
    Get(Float_2);
    Put("The greatest value was: ");

    if Float_1 > Float_2 then 
        Put(Float_1, Fore => 0, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);
    elsif Float_2 > Float_1 then
        Put(Float_2, Fore => 0, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);
    end if;       
end Test;
```

Although it works, I feel like I've overcomplicated it and haven't executed it well. For instance I haven't even used my subprogram Value at all in my main program, which I should do.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What will happen when the two floats are equal?

Comment: _Elements of Programming Style_ (Kernighan & Plauger, 2nd ed., 1978) presents 10 lines of complicated Fortran 66 to find the smallest of 3 values. They point out that this can be reduced by an order of magnitude to 1 line using the standard function `AMIN`, but if the point is to show how to do such a computation, 3 much clearer lines suffice. This seems like a similar exercise, with the added bonus that it's wrong: real code should use the standard function `Float'Max`, and an exercise to write an equivalent expression function takes 1 or 2 lines.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a better name for `Value` is `Max_Value`.  The conditional within it is also not exhaustive. If the two numbers are equal, there is no return value. This can be corrected by using `>=` instead of `>`, at which point the only other option is that `Float_2` is greater.

```
function Max_Value(Float_1, Float_2 : in Float) return Float is
begin
    if Float_1 >= Float_2 then
        return Float_1;
    else
        return Float_2;
    end if;
end Max_Value;
```

Alternatively, as suggested by others, the attribute `'Max` on `Float` can accomplish this much more concisely.

```
function Max_Value(Float_1, Float_2 : in Float) return Float is
begin
    return Float'Max(Float_1, Float_2);
end Max_Value;
```

Or even more concisely:

```
function Max_Value(Float_1, Float_2 : in Float) return Float renames Float'Max;
```

Having the ability to pick the larger of two Floats using `Max_Value` there's now no need to have a conditional later on.

```
Put(Max_Value(Float_1, Float_2), Fore => 0, Aft => 2, Exp => 0);
```

Comment: Smart, but why did you place Float_1 before Float_2 in your main program? Does it matter where you put them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Could you put

Put(Max_Value(Float_2, Float_1)); 

instead of Put(Max_Value(Float_1, Float_2));

Comment: The fact that the names are the same means _nothing_. One set of names are variables in `Test`. The others are arguments/parameters for the `Max_Value` function. I could rewrite the header for `Max_Value` as `function Max_value(f1, f2 : in Float) return Float`. However, given that `Max_Value` compares two Floats and returns the value of the larger one... there is no difference between calling `Max_Value(Float_1, Float_2)` and `Max_Value(Float_2, Float_1)`.

Comment: The scalar attribute `'Max` will do the same as the `Max_Value` function. Use it like `float'Max (float_1, Float_2)`. [Scalar Types](http://ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-3-5.html#I1622)

Comment: Further proof that most academic programming exercises are simultaneously incredibly important _and_ completely pointless. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another approach uses a conditional expression:

```
function Max_Value (Float_1, Float_2 : in float) return float is
   (if Float_1 > Float_2 then Float_1 else Float_2);
```

The conditional expression does the same thing as you were attempting while eliminating the need to return from the function in two different places.
Note that the logic simply returns Float_1 if it is greater than Float_2, otherwise it returns Float_2. Obviously, returning Float_2 when the two values are equal is a valid consequence of this logic.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, Ada already provides this functionality. Thus, the most concise implementation would be

```vhdl
with Ada.Text_IO;       use Ada.Text_IO;   
with Ada.Float_Text_IO; use Ada.Float_Text_IO;

procedure Test is
   function Max_Value (Left, Right : Float) return Float renames Float'Max;
begin
    Put ("Type in two numbers: ");
    Get (Float_1);
    Get (Float_2);
    Put ("The greatest value was: ");
    Put (Max_Value (Float_1, Float_2));
end Test;
```

What you do here is declare a function `Max_Value` that renames the existing `Float'Max` function. Other answers have shown you how to implement the logic yourself.